# How do I return columns starting with a particular prefix in KDB?

Tags: kdb

Say for example I have a table:

```
q)([] aa: til 5; ab: til 5; bb: til 5)

aa ab bb
--------
0  0  0
1  1  1
2  2  2
3  3  3
4  4  4
```

Is there a simple way of querying for just the columns that begin with `a`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use functional select

```
?[t;();0b;{x!x}cols[t] where cols[t] like "a*"]
```

https://code.kx.com/q/basics/funsql/

Answer (score 1):

If your table is in-memory and unkeyed then take (`#`) can also do it for you:

```
{where[c!(c:cols x)like"a*"]#x}t
```

But Matts solution is more general and thus more useful!